# How to approach caching in a web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, caching, memcached

this might be a more general question, not just Rails related. I'm about to start working on an application that will need to employ some kind of caching strategy sooner or later.

How to approach caching when programming a web application? Should I think it through up front or is it a matter of a later decisions? And then, how to approach testing of such application? Do you test it with caching turned on (after all, that's how it's going to be run in production) or off?

Comment: hi, you should think about it but not worry about it when you start your project. Just implement a clean design and keep it structured. This allows you to implement caching when needed. Independently of rails you could have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663208/php-caching-html-php/3663260#3663260

Answer (score 2):

There's a well done serie of screencasts about the subject here: http://railslab.newrelic.com/2009/01/22/introduction
whatch all the cache related episodes,they show both concepts and what options you have in rails